# Jboss as7 monitoring HTTP Listener Threads

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, monitoring

I want to monitor HTTP Listener Threads at jboss as 7. How can I do this? 
Are there any MBeans, witch allows to do this?

Web subsystem contains only general information but I want to monitor:

- `http-thread-max`
- `http-thread-current`
- `http-thread-busy`
- `http-thread-spare-max`
- `http-thread-spare-min`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use Mbean for Thread pool monitoring:

- [Memory and Thread Monitoring](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Services-Memory_and_Thread_Monitoring.html).
- [JBoss Performance Tuning part 1 - Tune JBoss Thread Pools](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-performance/jboss-performance-tuning-part-1/page-3)

Also, check out the **jBoss console**, I think there should be a tab with Thread pools - listing sizes, business, etc.

As a last resort, **collect thread dumps** and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it Ales. I think I'll update the article to include as 7 configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I need to get information about HttpThreads, not only jvm threads. 
I modified thread subsystem of standalone.xml and via Jboss DMR I got http thread metric.

```
ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set("read-resource");
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem", "threads");
request.get("recursive").set(true);
request.get("include-runtime").set(true);
final ModelNode response = client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build());
return response.get(ClientConstants.RESULT).get("bounded-queue-thread-pool").get("http_queue");
```

Standalone.xml thread subsystem looks like:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1">
<thread-factory name="my_tf" group-name="group1" thread-name-pattern="my_tf_" priority="1"/>
<bounded-queue-thread-pool name="http_queue" allow-core-timeout="true">
<core-threads count="100"/>
<queue-length count="50"/>
<max-threads count="200"/>
<keepalive-time time="30" unit="minutes"/>
<thread-factory name="my_tf"/>
</bounded-queue-thread-pool>
</subsystem>
```